# pip --version is working but python --version is not

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, environment-variables

I downloaded Python 3.8 in Windows 10 and added the environment variable.
When I do this,

```
set PATH=%PATH;C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
```

`python --version` works but `pip --version` throws

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When the change the path to set

```
PATH=%PATH;C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts
```

`python --version` throws

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

and `pip --version` works

Comment: So why not add both folders to the PATH? Am I missing something? I don't code on Windows.

Comment: I tried doing that but it is still not working

Comment: What's not working? Python or pip?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts`.

`%VAR_NAME%` represent the value of variable.

Comment: You can try `echo %PATH%` to check if the path is right

Comment: As you can see, `C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38` is not in your path, I recommend you restart your terminal and remember to use `%PATH%` instead of `%PATH`

Comment: Thanks. The problem is fixed.